# double request on ajax call first get status 400 second get status 200

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following action to create a record:

```
def create
    @categorization = Categorization.new(categorization_params)
    @categorization.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {  render json: {categorization: @categorization.to_json},  success: 200  }
    end
  end

  private
  def categorization_params
    params.require(:categorization).permit(:user_id, :category_id)
  end
```

and this is my jquery ajax code:

```
$("#save-category").click(function(){
    var category_id = $('#categorization_category_id').val();
    var category_name = $('#categorization_category_id  option:selected').text();
    var user_id = "#{current_user.id}";
    var cat_id;
    $.ajax({
      url: "#{dashboard_categorizations_path}",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType : 'json',
      data: {'user_id': user_id, 'category_id': category_id},
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        // cat_id = JSON.parse(result.id);
        // alert(cat_id);
      },
      error: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        // cat_id = JSON.parse(result.id);
        // alert(cat_id);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
    $("#categoriamensaje").show();
    var leadMessage = setInterval(function(){
          $("#categoriamensaje").hide();
        }, 3000);
  });
```

This is what my inspector show me:

[image]

As you can see, after make click on the button I get to responds I with status 400 and one with status 200:

The first one give me the following response:

> ## ActionController::ParameterMissing at /dashboard/categorizations
>
> > param is missing or the value is empty: categorization
>
> ### app/controllers/dashboard/categorizations_controller.rb, line 30
>
> ``` ruby    25       redirect_to
>   edit_dashboard_home_path(current_user.id)    26     end    27       28
>   private    29     def categorization_params
>
> > 30       params.require(:categorization).permit(:user_id, :category_id)    31     end    32   end

```

and the second one:

```
categorization:"{"id":60,"user_id":1,"category_id":7,"created_at":"2015-04-15T14:27:55.039Z","updated_at":"2015-04-15T14:27:55.039Z"}"
```

The record is created, but I need to catch the ajax response in order to show the information in the view.

Some help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to wrap the JSON payload you are posting in a `categorization` object like this:

```
{ "categorization": { "user_id" : "1", "category_id" : "1" } }
```

So your JQuery code should look something like this:

```
data: { 'categorization' : { 'user_id': user_id, 'category_id': category_id} }
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, it helps a lot